# Button not creating new file when pressed in Java Swing application

Tags: java, file, swing, file-io

So this is just a window with a button, when that button is pressed a new internal window opens with three textboxes and an ok button. when the ok button in the internal window is pressed, it should create a new file, but it's not, does anybody know why?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class tuna extends JFrame {

    private JButton button1, ok;
    private JTextField nameOfSong, artist;
    private JTextArea lyrics;
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    JInternalFrame internalFrame;

    Formatter x;

    public tuna() {
        super("iLyrics");

        desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        getContentPane().add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button1 = new JButton("Add a Song");
        getContentPane().add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);

    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource()==button1)
                internalGui();
        }
    }

    public void internalGui(){
        // Add a Song

        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame(
                "Internal Frame", true, true, true, true);
        internalFrame.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        desktop.add(internalFrame, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        // desktop.add(internalFrame);
        final JTextField nameOfSong = new JTextField("song");
        final JTextField artist = new JTextField("artist");
        final JTextArea lyrics = new JTextArea("lyrics");
        JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
        internalFrame.add(nameOfSong, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        internalFrame.add(artist, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
        internalFrame.add(lyrics, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        internalFrame.add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        ok.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        try {
                            FileWriter dir = new FileWriter("test.txt");
                            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(dir);
                            buffer.write(nameOfSong.getText());
                            buffer.newLine();
                            buffer.write(artist.getText());
                            buffer.newLine();
                            buffer.write(lyrics.getText());
                            buffer.close();
                        } catch (Exception z) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            System.err.println("Error: " + z.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the example: Q: could you show us your "main()"?

Comment: This is one of those problems where you 1st should've tried creating a `File` from a command line program.  Doing that would have confirmed that the problem has **nothing** to do with Swing.

Answer (score 3):

> but it's not, does anybody know why?

It probably does create it, in the current working directory - may not be what you want.
Check there (if using IDE, see launch properties for directory), or  try with an absolute path first "c:\\tmp\\myfile.txt", "/home/myhome/myfile.txt"..

Follow up Q from comment:

> i want the name of the file to be the text from nameOfSong.getText()...  new FileWriter("nameOfSong.getText().txt"), it wont make

```
new FileWriter(nameOfSong.getText() + ".txt" )
```

as per another comment.

Comment: yep was looking in the wrong place, now can i ask a follow up q? what if i want the name of the file to be the text from nameOfSong.getText(), how would i pass that to the FileWriter? because if i pass it as FileWriter dir = new FileWriter("nameOfSong.getText().txt"), it wont make since? sory if this is newbie question, it's cause i am a newbie..

Answer (score 3):

I'll bet that it does create the file, but that you may be looking in the wrong place for it. Do you know where it's writing the file?

Put this line of code in your program to find out:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: wow you're right i was looking in the wrong place. thanks. that's a cool little method tho

Comment: follow up, what if i want the name of the file to be the text from nameOfSong.getText(), how would i pass that to the FileWriter? because if i pass it as FileWriter dir = new FileWriter("nameOfSong.getText().txt"), it wont make since? sory if this is newbie question, it's cause i am a newbie..

Comment: 1) `"nameOfSong.getText().txt"` should probably be `nameOfSong.getText()+".txt"` 2) When you get a chance, please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Don't put `nameOfSong.getText()` in quotes. This method returns a String so you don't need quotes around the method call. Then append ".txt" to it if you desire by using `+ ".txt"`

Comment: BTW - Is `nameOfSong.getText()` guaranteed to only return 'letters, numbers and spaces'?  If it includes characters like `./;:()^`.. it would pay to run it through a method that removes those extra characters, otherwise they might be considered part of the file **path** (as opposed to just the name) or otherwise be illegal in a file name.